# Does the equation $2\cos^2 (x/2) \sin^2 (x/2) = x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$ have real solution?

Tags: trigonometry

> Do the equation
>   $$2\cos^2 (x/2) \sin^2 (x/2) = x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$$
>   have any real solutions?

Please help. This is an IITJEE question.
Here $x$ is an acute angle.
I cannot even start to attempt this question. I cannot understand.

Comment: Would be nice to write your equation with parenthesis to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Is it $2\cos^2(x/2)\sin^2(x/2) = \frac{x^2+1}{x^2}$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by $x^+1/x^2$?

Comment: Lhs is correct Rhs=(x^2)+1/(x^2)

Comment: Hint: First use the addition formula $\sin(2t) = 2\sin(t)\cos(t)$ with $t=x/2$ to simplify. Next try to factorize the rhs (after putting everything on one fraction).

Comment: Can you show that $\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta < 1$?

Answer (score 4):

the right hand of the equation, you have $$x^2 + \frac1{x^2} = \left(x-\frac 1x\right)^2 + 2 \ge 2 \tag 1$$and equality occurs for $$x = \pm 1.$$

on the left hand side, we have $$ \frac12 \sin^2 x = 2\cos^2 (x/2) \sin^2 (x/2) \le \frac12 \tag 2$$ equality for $$\sin x = \pm 1.$$

but $(1)$ and $(2)$ are inconsistent, therefore $$2\cos^2 (x/2) \sin^2 (x/2) = x^2+\frac{1}{x^2} $$ has no real solutions.

Comment: Actually, $2\cos^2(x/2)\sin^2(x/2)\le \frac12$.  But the conclusion retains!

Comment: @Dr.MV, thanks. hopefully is fixed now.

Comment: You're welcome!! +1

Answer (score 1):

Observe $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2} \geq 2$, and simplify left hand side using $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

We have

$$2\cos^2(x/2)\sin^2(x/2)=\frac12\sin^2x\le \frac12$$

while

$$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\ge 2$$

Answer (score 0):

In the same spirit as baharampuri's answer, the equation write $$\frac{\sin ^2(x)}{2}=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$$ The lhs is almays $< \frac 12$ while the rhs is $\geq 2$.

For the last point, consider $$y==x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$$ $$y'=2 x-\frac{2}{x^3}$$ $$y''=2+\frac{6}{x^4}$$ So, $y'=0$ for $x=\pm 1$ and at this point $y=2$. The second derivative test proves that this is a minimum.

Comment: Simpler: if |x| < 1 then |1/x| > 1, so right > 1 which is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
LHS in blue, RHS in green.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alphy says no real roots and the complex ones are
approximately
$ \pm 0.866835 \pm 0.733199 i$
and
$\pm 1.63597 i$.